# Filter in inventory host file with ansible

Tags: ansible

Do you know if it is possible to have a filter in the inventory host file ?

For example :

```
[RHEL-server]
evxs1*
```

or

```
[RHEL-server]
^evxs1*
```

I tried but it does not work.

Comment: Did you see this doc https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html?

Comment: What would this be used for? The inventory file is used to list all of the hosts that you would apply your playbooks to, it's your master list of all the hosts that you want to work on. If you use wildcards in there, where would Ansible get the actual list of hosts from? From DNS? That might have severe results, e.g. if you try to apply this to all hosts found in DNS...